# Disabling old devices support for developed app in xcode

Tags: xcode, compilation, device, iphone-4

got an IOS app and I wantto support only new devices.
eg. I wantto remove iphone4 support because of people may buy accidently that my app doesnt support that device.
somehow there is no option for this in xcode.In xcode there is only universal/iphone/ipad options.
but looking something an option to choose (remove iphone4)

in conclusion:
need to disable old devices to be purchased.
in xcode, itunesconnect and appstore.
and dont wanto add a top description (this app does not support iphone4.if you buy this app.Im not responsible of any trouble)

any better idea except adding a negative sentence into app description ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way that you can disable support for that until Apple decides to disable support for the iPhone 4/4S, if you try to do this Apple will not accept your app because it does not follow their guidelines, you can create a smaller/not as powerful version of the app for those devices but you cannot cut them out completely