# Disable iPhone app for older versions of iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iOS app, and I only want it to run on iPhone 6 and 6 plus, how do I disable the app for older versions of iPhone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling old devices support for developed app in xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874979/disabling-old-devices-support-for-developed-app-in-xcode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prevent users from downloading it off of the app store. I suggest that you use auto layout to allow your objects to be displayed properly on all display sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Get iOS device version in AppDelegate and show message there this device not supporting iOS 7 or previous

**Use them like this:**

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"5.0")) {
    // code here
}

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {
    // code here
}
```

---

## Outdated version below

to get OS version:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

returns string, which can be turned into int/float via

```
-[NSString floatValue]
-[NSString intValue]
```

like this

> Both values (floatValue, intValue) will be stripped due to its type, 5.0.1 will become 5.0 or 5 (float or int), for comparing precisely, you will have to separate it to array of INTs
>      check accepted answer here: [Check iPhone iOS Version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3339787/492624)

```
NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
int ver_int = [ver intValue];
float ver_float = [ver floatValue];
```

and compare like this

```
NSLog(@"System Version is %@",[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
float ver_float = [ver floatValue];
if (ver_float < 5.0) return false;
```

Comment: This isn't what the question is about.

Comment: you can't do it.this is the trick that any body can download just you want to limit your functionalities by checking version.
it also limiting the user.